# Composable transparency

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Is there any way to make composable transparent the same way Image can be done with alpha example:

```
Image(
    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.flower),
    contentDescription = null,
    alpha = 0.2F)
```

I am aware of making background and text transparent, but is there any way to make the whole composable component transparent with parameter `alpha = 0.5F`

[image: transparency]

Answer (score 2):

If you set `Modifier.alpha(0.5f)` on a Composable contents of that Composable will also have same alpha

`Modifier.graphicsLayer{alpha =0.5f}` does the same thing.